# "TS2339: Property ... does not exist on type ...", on input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an input field which, when a user clicks a certain button, needs to be focused and have its text value selected entirely (that way when users type, they replace the entire value).

Here's the input field's markup:

```html
<input type="text" id="descriptionField" class="form-control">
```

...and the function responsible for focus/select:

```js
public copy(): void {
    document.getElementById("descriptionField").focus();
    document.getElementById("descriptionField").select();
}
```

`.focus()` works fine, but `.select()` throws an error:

```
TS2339: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

I've tried looking for solutions but most of them rely on jQuery. Is there any way to solve this with native implementation, or with TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "type-cast" the `HTMLElement` to [a type which has the `select` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-6043025):

```
(document.getElementById("descriptionField") as HTMLInputElement).select();
```

or:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("descriptionField")).select();
```

This basically tells the compiler *"don't worry, I know what type is expected here."*, and is called *[Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)* in TypeScript.

It does not affect the runtime, just reassures the compiler so it won't have anything to complain about.